# wait ajax finish in a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object with function foo containing a jQuery ajax call

```
foo: function() {
    ...
    jQuery.ajax({
            contentType : "application/json",
            type: "POST",
            async: true,
            ...,
            success: function(data) {
               globalVariable = 1;           
            },
            error: function(error) {
            }
    });
}
```

My test code:

```
    var pass = true;
    myObj.foo();

    if (globalVariable !== 1) {
        pass = false;
    }
```

I want statement `myObj.foo()` finish with ajax finish too. If ajax does not finish, the `globalVariable` is not equal to 1.

I cannot set `async` to `false` in ajax because that is production code.

Comment: globalVariable should be set to `1` with this function, you would just need to wait until the call has completed. Perhaps look at passing callback functions to `foo()` that would notify you when `success`/`error` has been called. Alternatively you could look into jQuery promises: https://api.jquery.com/promise/

Comment: Don't do this synchronously, @Vu Le Anh. Make your `foo` function promisable is recommended nowadays, I think. Then you can do checking   `globalVariable` upon `done` callback of promise function in which that variable would be passed as a parameter in the callback.

Comment: What you're asking is not possible if you are unable to set `async` to false. Javascript is single-threaded. So the ajax code is added to the execution queue after foo and will only start running AFTER foo function completes its turn.  If you put anything in the foo function to wait until the ajax call completes then it will run forever with the ajax call never starting.

Comment: @BobDust could you guide me how can do that? I have no idea about `promise` or `done`. I try `jQuery.when(myObj.foo()).done(function() { //checking here });. 
But it does not work.

Comment: @VuLeAnh, answer has been added :)

Answer (score 1):

Your function is running. It's just that it's running asychrounously. If you want to halt your other processes while foo() runs, set **async** to **false**.

```
foo: function() {
    ...
    jQuery.ajax({
            contentType : "application/json",
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            ...,
            success: function(data) {
               globalVariable = 1;           
            },
            error: function(error) {
            }
    });
}
```

Comment: I edit my question.  I cannot change `async: false` as your comment

Answer (score 0):

If that's the case add a function parameter to foo instead. That function will be called after the ajax call has finished.

```
var bar = function(){
  pass=true;
}
```

Then foo will become

```
foo: function(func) {
    ...
    jQuery.ajax({
            contentType : "application/json",
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            ...,
            success: function(data) {
               globalVariable = 1;
               func();           
            },
            error: function(error) {
            }
    });
}
```

Call foo

```
var pass = false;
myObj.foo(bar);
```

Answer (score 0):

A code snippet follows `promise` approach:

```
    var pass = true;
    var myObj = {
        foo: function () {
            return $.Deferred(function (deferred) {
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'https://httpbin.org/post'
                }).done(function () {
                    deferred.resolve(1);
                }).fail(function () {
                    deferred.reject();
                });
            }).promise();
        }
    };
    myObj.foo().done(function (globalVariable) {
        if (globalVariable !== 1) {
            pass = false;
        }
    });
```